# My react app reads firestore on every render, how to reduce read and save bandwidth?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> Data doesnt change, its constant and i only read it to show the user the data

```
const Course = () => {
    
    const coursedb = getFirestore();
 
    const history = useHistory()

    
  const [courses, setCourse] = useState([]);

 >"my use effect for fetching the data inside firestore"

  useEffect(
    () => {

      const collectionRef = collection(coursedb, "courses");
      const q = query(collectionRef,orderBy("courseDifficulty","asc"));
      onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) =>
        setCourse(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })))

      )
      
    },[coursedb]
    
  );
```

> this is what i use to throw the data inside my app

```
const showCourse = courses.map((courses) => (  <div key={courses.id} className="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12">

<div className="single-feature wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay=".4s">
<img className="w-64" src={courses.courseimg} alt={courses.coursename} />
<h3>{courses.coursename}</h3>
<p>{courses.coursedesc}</p>
<p><FcIcons.FcClock/> Duration {courses.courseduration} hrs</p>
<Button  onClick={handler}  data-id={courses.id} >Get Started</Button>
</div>
</div>
```

))

**i want to reduce the data usage in firebase by lessening the read, can you guys give me tips on how to lessen it?**

Comment: Hey, could you refer to this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/optimize) on optimizing database performance once.